# print in SwiftUI project not working in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've done some research online and the most common solution was to activate the debug console but unfortunately, it still did not work for me, please see attached image for details (I was expecting abc to get printed but nothing was in the console.)

[image]

Comment: If you mean in Preview then they disabled this a couple of versions ago - run in Simulator.

Comment: yeah seems like it, thanks.